# Dynamic where clause based on input parameters in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a jsonb parameter to my plsql procedure with data {1=2,2=3}. My Table contains the following data,

```
att_name |att_key |att_value
abcd     |1       |2
bcde     |2       |3
efgh     |1       |3
```

I want to filter out the data where (att_key = 1 and att_value = 2) or (att_key = 2 and att_value = 3) which should be dynamically generated based on the jsonb input.The output will contain abcd and bcde only. Is there any way to create this query dynamically in postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{1=2,2=3}` is not a valid JSON.

I think you mean `{"1":"2","2":"3"}`.

You may use `json_each_text` to convert to key value pair (text) and compare easily.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM   t 
WHERE  ( att_key, att_value ) IN (SELECT inp.key :: INT, inp.VALUE :: INT 
     FROM   json_each_text('{"1":"2","2":"3"}') AS inp );
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d900e435903397f44ee5d61688710daa)